# After adding FORWARD NAT rules, cannot connect system eth0

Tags: networking, centos

I was trying to make bridge connection between wlan and eth on Centos..

I made Forward and NAT rules and then something wrong with System eth0 connection. It does not connect anymore..

Could you help me how to solve this issue? How can I go back working eth0 settings ?

Edit :  Here is what I did from command line

```
 iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -A FORWARD -o eth1 -j ACCEPT

 sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Comment: Is the routing table ok? Does the connection work again if you undo the iptables/sysctl settings?

Comment: I do not know how to undo this settings..Could you describe it ?

Comment: With undo, I mean, delete the new iptables rules (`iptables -D FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT` and `iptables -D FORWARD -o eth1 -j ACCEPT`) and `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=0`. As the default policy for the FORWARD table is ACCEPT, if you do not use any other firewall settings, the iptables rules could have no influence anyway.